# A single word for a building located in the centre of fork (intersection)?

Tags: single-word-requests, speech

So there is this kind of building located in the centre of a fork in the road (maybe in streets too).

I don't know how to put it into words, but it looks like this:
[image: A black and white drawing of two top down road layouts. One is cul-de-sac with houses down either side and one at the end, the house at the end is circled in red. The other is a T junction with a house opposite the stem of the T. The house is circled in red.]

Or this:

[image: A front on drawing of a house in a corner of a Y junction. It has empty flowerbeds and a tree at the back, on the right hand side.]

Is there a single English word for that kind of building? If it is a house, is there another name for that?

In my native language (Indonesian), it's called *Rumah Tusuk Sate*. Which if translated bluntly into English, it's *Skewer House*, which sounds a bit weird to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is colloquially mentioned as "***t-junction house***" because the house is located at a t-junction. (first image, depiction on the right)

[image: A top down drawing of a house oppposite the stem of a T juction.] 
<sub><sup>~Source: http://rol.vn/resourcedetail/1/1044/the-dreaded-tjunction/</sup></sub>

There is also ***y-junction house*** (second image)

[image: A top down drawing of a house opposite the stem of a Y junction.] 
<sub><sup>~Source: http://rol.vn/resourcedetail/1/1044/the-dreaded-tjunction/</sup></sub>

---

In the first image, the depiction on the left is the *last house in a cul-de-sac* (or *house at the dead end*).

Comment: I think your question is feng shui related :)

Comment: Is *cul-de-sac* English too? How do I pronounce it?

Comment: Yes it is English. It is loaned from French. You can hear the pronunciation in online dictionaries. For example: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cul-de-sac

Comment: Neitherof the links are working. Are there any examples of T-junction/Y-junction house? Or is this coining a phrase?

Comment: I think the examples are shown above the links (images).

Answer (score 0):

This type of home is also referred to as a [**T-intersection home**](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=Fxbp7HSnoXAC&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=%22t+intersection+home%22&source=bl&ots=a7qruSKKO5&sig=O9_2lFtDI4DsIcGul1XoJvErz-A&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=cyKRU4eFPO2c0wWZ_4CICg&ved=0CFcQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22t%20intersection%20home%22&f=false) (or *house*).

> [T-intersection](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/T-intersection): *US* a place where one road joins another and forms the shape of the letter T

Answer (score 0):

I have always heard it referred to as a 'sandwich building' but it is a  Flatiron Building.

> **[Pullman Flatiron Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullman_Flatiron_Building#One_of_a_Kind_in_Pullman)** This corner of Main Street and Grand Avenue is the only triangular plat of land in the town, because
>   it is a location where two different street grids meet.[21] Often
>   larger cities have this occurrence and a flatiron building is born,
>   becoming an icon for that city or neighborhood, but it is not as
>   common in smaller towns that have less complicated grid systems

[**Flatiron Building**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatiron_Building) in NYC (aerial photo)

Comment: I think the building needs to be triangular to be called "Flatiron"

Answer (score 0):

Corner House

A house located at a corner, or a place where a road bends, or there is an intersection.

Lyon's Corner House is a famous example; it was the first ever coffee shop, at which the stock exchange grew, in London.

It also became a well-known chain of coffee houses.

https://flashbak.com/the-rise-and-fall-of-the-lyons-cornerhouses-and-their-nippy-waitresses-35186/